# Return function pointing to local var in php

Tags: php, variables, methods, return

```
class Person{

     var $name = "Omer";

     function get_name(){
         return $this->name;//Why not $this->$name ?
     }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `$this->$name` it will actually look for a property in `$this` with the name of whatever `$name` is equal to. So, in your example, `$this->$name` would look for `$this->Omer`.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate what @Aaron has so eloquently answered, the following would compile:

```
class Person{
     var $name = "Omer";
     function get_name(){
         $varname = 'name';
         return $this->$varname;
     }
}
$Person = new Person;
echo $Person->get_name(); // output = Omer
```